# Checkbox is not checking though attribute values are updating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox which I want to check/uncheck using setInterval in every 2 secs.

But it is getting checked/unchecked only once.

Also when I am inspecting the DOM , I can see it's value and `checked` attribute is updating, but it is not reflecting in the view.

Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="paid" id="paid-change" value = "1">
```

**JS**

```
var getCheckBox = $("#paid-change");

function check(){
 getCheckBox.attr('checked',true);
 getCheckBox.val("1")
}
function uncheck(){
getCheckBox.attr('checked',false);
 getCheckBox.val("0")
}

// check/uncheck in every 2 seconds
setInterval(function(){
 switch (getCheckBox.val()){ //get checkbox value
 case "0":
     check() // if value is 0 check it
     break;
 case "1":
     uncheck() //uncheck it
     break;
}

},2000)
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdg3cddu/).

Inspecting the element,you the attributes are updating but not reflecting on the view.

Any idea where I am making mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `attr()` to set `checked` attribute, use `prop()`.

```
getCheckBox.prop('checked', true);
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hdg3cddu/1/)

---

The code can be rewritten as

```
// Cache checkbox object
var checkbox = $("#paid-change");

// Function to toggle the checkbox value and state
function toggleCheckbox() {
    // Change the 'checked' property
    checkbox.prop('checked', function(i, checked) {
        return !checked;                           // Invert the checked status
    }).val(function(i, val) {
        return +this.checked;                      // Change the value
    });
}

setInterval(toggleCheckbox, 2000);                 // Call the function after each 2 seconds
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/4pk6p7eb/)

Answer (score 4):

Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to check or uncheck any checkbox

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/a9p1wqm1/

```
getCheckBox.prop('checked',false);
```

Comment: I am sorry I can accept only one answer since Tushar answered a minute before you so I accepted his answer, but have upvoted your answer. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user2181397 You should see [Which answer do I accept if I have multiple correct answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13396/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-i-have-multiple-correct-answers)